# Vulnerability Across EVM Networks: Can a Single Transaction Compromise All Funds?

Tags: transactions, digital-signature, evm

Is it possible to sign just ONE transaction, for instance, in the BNB, Polygon, Arbitrum, or Optimism networks, and lose all funds across all EVM networks simultaneously? Or would the threat from a scam transaction/signature only impact funds in the current network?

I'm simply curious to know: if I accidentally sign a scam transaction in an L2 solution or a testnet EVM, could I potentially lose funds in the Mainnet?